# Not able to use interval on long type columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have a spark table of below data types

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- visit_time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hit_time: long (nullable = true)

+---+----------+--------+
| id|visit_time|hit_time|
+---+----------+--------+
|  1|1664994234|   15612|
|  2|1664945623|28098141|
+---+----------+--------+
```

I am trying to add an interval to my visit_time column with below sql

```
select id,visit_time,
cast(visit_time as TIMESTAMP),
cast(visit_time as TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL CAST(round((hit_time/1000),0) AS int) second as hit_cst,
hit_time,
CAST(round((hit_time/1000),0) AS int) as dt 
from tbl
```

The sql is failing in line no 3 while calculating hit_cst.
If I try to run them indiviaully every part is working.

Can Someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

try `, cast(visit_time as TIMESTAMP) + make_interval(0,0,0,0,0,0,hit_time/1000) as hit_cst`